# How to cache images sent in server response without adding caching headers?

Tags: jquery, html, caching, browser-cache

I'm a complete noob to caching and to top it off, for reasons beyond my control, I cannot add/modify my response header sent from my servlet (ridiculous I know). Is there any other way I can tell the user's browser to cache the images similar to a typical Last-Modified or Expires header? I've heard of ways of doing it in jquery but all I've seen is jquery image pre-loading which isn't the same thing.

Comment: If you have caching enabled and you do not set a Last-Modified or Expires header, then on the first page load the element will be downloaded. then, for all subsequent page vists, that image remains in cache until:  1) You tell the browsers that the image is old or 2) Until the user clears their cache. Also, there are millions of different ways to cache data. Memcache, session variables, cookies, databases..these are all examples. You have to find one that fits your mold and then work with it. Once you've done that, come back here for help making the code finite.

Comment: What about when the user closes their browser? I'm confused as to why it's taking so long for my images to load. I frankly assumed that it was because I had not specified any caching.

Comment: If you want to know if the browser serves the images from cache, open the page in chrome or safari and after loading hit F12 (or right mouse click on the page and select "inspect element"). Select the "Network" tab and refresh the page. Then look for the image you want to check out in the list. If the "Size" column says "From cache" then you know it came from the browsers cache. Als if the timeline on the right  is long then you know it took al long time to load that specific image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my requests to call from a new servlet that I made so that I could modify/add headers so simply bypassed the issue I was having.